# How can I drop NaN values as well as nearby non-Nan values from a df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have large CSVs (~100k rows x 30 cols). Occasionally the data has sections of `nan` values which span sections of the `df` of various sizes. I need to drop the `nan`s but also ~3 data points either side because the non-`nan` data either side is borked.

One could drop any row containing a `nan` but this would throw away more data than needs to be.

How can I do this with python? The data has been loaded into a `df`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a','b','c', np.nan, 'd','e',np.nan, 's','r'],
                   'col1':4})

print (df)
   col  col1
0    a     4
1    b     4
2    c     4
3  NaN     4
4    d     4
5    e     4
6  NaN     4
7    s     4
8    r     4

#test at least one missing value
m = df.isna().any(axis=1)

#test row above and bellow match value by mask, chain by | for bitwise OR
#filter in inverted mask by ~ in boolean indexing
df = df[~(m | m.shift(fill_value=False) | m.shift(-1, fill_value=False))]
print (df)
  col  col1
0   a     4
1   b     4
8   r     4
```

Alternative solution:

```
m = df.notna().all(axis=1)

df = df[(m & m.shift(fill_value=True) & m.shift(-1, fill_value=True))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way if the number of rows to look above and below might change.

```
l = 1

(df.loc[~df.isna().any(axis=1)
        .replace(False,None,method = 'ffill',limit= l)
        .replace(False,None,method = 'bfill',limit= l)])
```